# "is not a member of package" error when importing package in Scala with SBT

Tags: scala, classpath, package, sbt

(Relative beginner here, please be gentle...)

I've got a Scala program that I can build with sbt. I can (from within sbt) run `compile` and `test-compile` with no errors. I've defined a package by putting `package com.mycompany.mypackagename` at the top of several .scala files. When I do `console` to get a Scala REPL, this happens:

```
scala> import com.mycompany.mypackagename._     
<console>:5: error: value mypackagename is not a member of package com.mycompany
       import com.mycompany.mypackagename._
```

Any variation of this also fails. When I just do `import com.mycompany` I get no problems.

I thought that running the Scala console from within sbt would properly set the classpath based on the current projects? What (completely obvious) thing am I missing?

Comment: Oy. It appears to have been caused by some unknown wonkiness with the compiler, such that "clean" in sbt caused the problem to go away. So confused...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, and then I realized I was running scala 2.10.0 on commandline, and IDEA was using Scala 2.9.2. So the fix was to change both to use the same version, and:

```
sbt clean
```

Answer (score 0):

What will happen if you import actual class name instead of wildcard.

```
import com.mycompany.mypackagename.ActualClassName
```